# Are Cauchy-Euler ODEs common?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am progressing with solving 2nd order ODEs and stumbled upon [Cauchy-Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) differential equations of the form $$(at^2)y'' + (bt)y' + cy = f(t)$$ It explains how these are also called *equidimensional equations*. The book then goes on to show yet another very specific way of solving this specific ODE, quickly followed by a "most every other type of variable coefficient 2nd order ODE is not solvable."

This type of ODE seems to be **very** specific. There are infinitely many polynomial coefficients that could exist for the $y''$, $y'$, and $y$ terms. Are Cauchy-Euler equations so commonplace that there's a dedicated method for solving them (and if so, where do they arise most)? Or is it simply introduced as a bridge to solving harder variable-coefficient ODEs?

Comment: see [applications-of-euler-cauchy-odes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12628/applications-of-euler-cauchy-odes), the Cauchy-Euler ode is special case because it is I think the only ode with variable coefficients that can be solved using simple substitution. The typical case is that variable coefficients odes are very hard to solve. Kovacic algorithm for example is needed for the general case of ode with variable coefficients with the coefficients are rational polynomials of the independent variable. Other odes' have their own special other methods to solve, such as Bessel ode and more.

Comment: The reason ofcourse  why this is special is because the degree of $t$ in each term is the same the order of the derivative of $y$ w.r.t $t$. This is why using $y=t^r$ results in a characteristic equation with no $t$ in it which can be solved for $r$.  Any other degree on $t$ would not have made this possible. I think there are common in math text books, because they are only ones with variable coefficients that can be solved in easy way that students can understand. I do think there is any other reason really. Can you come up with second order ode with variable coefficients easier to solve?

Comment: Nope! I find that most ODE texts tend to simply say things along the lines of "what if our ODE did *this*? What if our ODE looked like *that*? And as someone trying to provide intuition and teach others about it, I'm always looking for intuitive explanations as to "why" we do certain things (and not the deep, mathy, proofy way of "why"). The takeaway I'm getting is that we start with this particular ODE variant because of the reason you stated--easy to solve with simple substitution. And then we continue to say "but pretty much every other type can't be solved" and go from there...

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: One reason for the interest in these equations is that the can be written in terms of the operator $\theta:f\mapsto xf'$ with constant coefficients. This is a diagonalizable differential operator (at least on polynomials, say) and is very special. There are reasons for this interest coming from the study of differential equations with regular singular points, the Hilbert-Riemann problem, and a huge part of the theory of differential equations...